# Помогите сделать такую анимацию стрелочки

Tags: jquery, анимация, css-animation, animate, svg-animation

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В течении пяти секунд она должна так заполнятся, не могу понять как это сделать

Comment: Воспользуйтесь функцией [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно использовать стрелку как текстовый символ и продублировать её псевдоэлементом с другим цветом.

```css
.arrow{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  font-size:50px;
  
}
.arrow:before{
  content:'↓';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  color:red;
  animation:arrow 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes arrow{
  to{
    height:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="arrow">↓</span>
```